# Turtle program in Python crashes with stack overflow

Tags: python, stack-overflow, turtle-graphics

I made a program to generate lines in random directions in Python turtle.  The way I did it is very repetitive, and it also crashes. My code recurses through functions repetitively. I have found it always crashes at about the 3215th recursion. I don't know if that's relevant. I'm asking if anyone knows why it's crashing and how to stop it. When it crashes, the turtle graphics window and cmd window both randomly close.
My code:

```
import turtle
import random
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

rminlength = 1
rmaxlength = 15
gminlength = 1
gmaxlength = 30
bminlength = 1
bmaxlength = 45

rminangle = 45
rmaxangle = 45
gminangle = 90
gmaxangle = 90
bminangle = 135
bmaxangle = 135

drawspeed = 10000
global recurse
recurse = 0

r = turtle.Turtle()
r.color('red')
r.pensize(3)
r.shape('circle')
r.speed(drawspeed)
r.hideturtle()

g = turtle.Turtle()
g.color('green')
g.pensize(3)
g.shape('circle')
g.speed(drawspeed)
g.hideturtle()

b = turtle.Turtle()
b.color('blue')
b.pensize(3)
b.shape('circle')
b.speed(drawspeed)
b.hideturtle()

#Movement

def rmove():
    if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
        r.left(random.randint(rminangle,rmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            r.forward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
        else:
            r.backward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
    else:
        r.right(random.randint(rminangle,rmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            r.forward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
        else:
            r.backward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
    global recurse
    recurse+=1
    print(recurse)
    gmove()

def gmove():
    if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
        g.left(random.randint(gminangle,gmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            g.forward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
        else:
            g.backward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
    else:
        g.right(random.randint(gminangle,gmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            g.forward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
        else:
            g.backward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
    global recurse
    recurse+=1
    print(recurse)
    bmove()

def bmove():
    if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
        b.left(random.randint(bminangle,bmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            b.forward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
        else:
            b.backward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
    else:
        b.right(random.randint(bminangle,bmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            b.forward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
        else:
            b.backward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
    global recurse
    recurse+=1
    print(recurse)
    rmove()

rmove()
input('Crashed')
```

Comment: What does "it cashes" mean in details?

Comment: Also please explain why you are doing this iterative process recursively.

Comment: @KlausD. When it crashes, the turtle graphics window and cmd window both randomly close. This is my first program with turtle. I didn't specifically mean to make it like that, that's just kind of how I made it. (very quickly)

Comment: For a newcomer in programming it might be better not to use recursion. Use loops instead. In general a function should do what it is supposed to do and not more. In your case it always starts the next function, adding that functionally to its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call a function, you're using memory in a finite region of data allocated to the program called the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). If these functions never resolve and continue calling other functions, the stack memory is never reclaimed. Eventually, your program runs out of memory. This is called a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Here's the actual error message from your program:

```
  ...
  File "a.py", line 100, in bmove
    rmove()
  File "a.py", line 64, in rmove
    gmove()
  File "a.py", line 82, in gmove
    bmove()
  File "a.py", line 99, in bmove
    print(recurse)
MemoryError: stack overflow
```

You've attempted to solve the problem by increasing the recursion limit that was set by Python, but this only postpones the inevitable. Even if some calls did resolve, increasing this number is an unsafe way to write code because it makes assumptions about stack size rather than rewriting program logic to ensure calls resolve and that the stack doesn't grow out of control.

Because recursion is unnecessary to obtain the sequential turtle movement you're going for, let's re-write your program to use loops rather than function calls to direct the turtles:

```
import turtle
import random
import sys


rminlength = 1
rmaxlength = 15
gminlength = 1
gmaxlength = 30
bminlength = 1
bmaxlength = 45

rminangle = 45
rmaxangle = 45
gminangle = 90
gmaxangle = 90
bminangle = 135
bmaxangle = 135

drawspeed = 10000

r = turtle.Turtle()
r.color('red')
r.pensize(3)
r.shape('circle')
r.speed(drawspeed)
r.hideturtle()

g = turtle.Turtle()
g.color('green')
g.pensize(3)
g.shape('circle')
g.speed(drawspeed)
g.hideturtle()

b = turtle.Turtle()
b.color('blue')
b.pensize(3)
b.shape('circle')
b.speed(drawspeed)
b.hideturtle()

#Movement

def rmove():
    if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
        r.left(random.randint(rminangle,rmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            r.forward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
        else:
            r.backward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
    else:
        r.right(random.randint(rminangle,rmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            r.forward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))
        else:
            r.backward(random.randint(rminlength,rmaxlength))

def gmove():
    if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
        g.left(random.randint(gminangle,gmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            g.forward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
        else:
            g.backward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
    else:
        g.right(random.randint(gminangle,gmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            g.forward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))
        else:
            g.backward(random.randint(gminlength,gmaxlength))

def bmove():
    if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
        b.left(random.randint(bminangle,bmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            b.forward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
        else:
            b.backward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
    else:
        b.right(random.randint(bminangle,bmaxangle))
        if(random.randint(1,2) == 1):
            b.forward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))
        else:
            b.backward(random.randint(bminlength,bmaxlength))

while 1: # loop infinitely
    rmove()
    gmove()
    bmove()
```

Specifically, the recursive calls were removed and a `while 1:` infinite loop was added.

---

As you mention, there is a lot of repetition in the code. Writing a class to encapsulate your turtle logic offers a significant cleanup opportunity and makes the program easily extensible to handle arbitrary numbers of additional turtles:

```
import turtle
from random import choice
from random import randint


class Turtle:
    def __init__(
        self, color, min_len, max_len, angle, speed=10, pensize=3
    ):
        self.min_len = min_len
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.angle = angle
        self.turt = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turt.color(color)
        self.turt.pensize(pensize)
        self.turt.speed(speed)
        self.turt.hideturtle()

    def move(self):
        choice((self.turt.left, self.turt.right))(self.angle)
        dir_func = choice((self.turt.forward, self.turt.backward))
        dir_func(randint(self.min_len, self.max_len))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    turtles = [
        Turtle("red", 1, 15, 45),
        Turtle("green", 1, 30, 90),
        Turtle("blue", 1, 45, 135)
    ]

    while 1:
        for turt in turtles:
            turt.move()
```

Happy turtling!

Comment: <obligatory stack overflow joke>

Comment: Note that the `speed` argument to `turtle.speed()` is limited to 0 - 10 so neither your 100 nor the OP's 100000 make sense.  There is an alternative symbolic option so I recommend `'fast'` or `'fastest'` for your default.

Comment: Nice object implementation (+1) though it might be more instrutive if it inherited from `Turtle` rather than contained a turtle...

Comment: I don't know much about turtle, so the advice is much appreciated. I'll look into the inheritance, but that might be more work than I have time for tonight.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, your code goes beyond 4000 calls without crashing.  But the point is, although where it will crash will be different on every sytem with various settings of `setrecursionlimit()`, it will eventually crash.

Since you don't use recursion to any advantage (nothing is learned or passed between recursions) except to emulate *coroutines*, let's emulate them without recursion, using generators:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

R_MIN_LENGTH, R_MAX_LENGTH = 1, 15
G_MIN_LENGTH, G_MAX_LENGTH = 1, 30
B_MIN_LENGTH, B_MAX_LENGTH = 1, 45

R_MIN_ANGLE, R_MAX_ANGLE = 45, 45
G_MIN_ANGLE, G_MAX_ANGLE = 90, 90
B_MIN_ANGLE, B_MAX_ANGLE = 135, 135

R_LIMIT = 1500
G_LIMIT = 1250
B_LIMIT = 1000

DRAW_SPEED = 'fastest'

# Movement

def rmove(turtle):
    count = 0

    while count < R_LIMIT:

        if choice([True, False]):
            turtle.left(randint(R_MIN_ANGLE, R_MAX_ANGLE))

            if choice([True, False]):
                turtle.forward(randint(R_MIN_LENGTH, R_MAX_LENGTH))
            else:
                turtle.backward(randint(R_MIN_LENGTH, R_MAX_LENGTH))
        else:
            turtle.right(randint(R_MIN_ANGLE, R_MAX_ANGLE))

            if choice([True, False]):
                turtle.forward(randint(R_MIN_LENGTH, R_MAX_LENGTH))
            else:
                turtle.backward(randint(R_MIN_LENGTH, R_MAX_LENGTH))

        count += 1
        yield count

def gmove(turtle):
    count = 0

    while count < G_LIMIT:

        if choice([True, False]):
            turtle.left(randint(G_MIN_ANGLE, G_MAX_ANGLE))

            if choice([True, False]):
                turtle.forward(randint(G_MIN_LENGTH, G_MAX_LENGTH))
            else:
                turtle.backward(randint(G_MIN_LENGTH, G_MAX_LENGTH))
        else:
            turtle.right(randint(G_MIN_ANGLE, G_MAX_ANGLE))

            if choice([True, False]):
                turtle.forward(randint(G_MIN_LENGTH, G_MAX_LENGTH))
            else:
                turtle.backward(randint(G_MIN_LENGTH, G_MAX_LENGTH))

        count += 1
        yield count

def bmove(turtle):
    count = 0

    while count < B_LIMIT:
        if choice([True, False]):
            turtle.left(randint(B_MIN_ANGLE, B_MAX_ANGLE))

            if choice([True, False]):
                turtle.forward(randint(B_MIN_LENGTH, B_MAX_LENGTH))
            else:
                turtle.backward(randint(B_MIN_LENGTH, B_MAX_LENGTH))
        else:
            turtle.right(randint(B_MIN_ANGLE, B_MAX_ANGLE))

            if choice([True, False]):
                turtle.forward(randint(B_MIN_LENGTH, B_MAX_LENGTH))
            else:
                turtle.backward(randint(B_MIN_LENGTH, B_MAX_LENGTH))

        count += 1
        yield count

r = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
r.color('red')
r.pensize(3)
r.speed(DRAW_SPEED)
red = rmove(r)

g = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
g.color('green')
g.pensize(3)
g.speed(DRAW_SPEED)
green = gmove(g)

b = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
b.color('blue')
b.pensize(3)
b.speed(DRAW_SPEED)
blue = bmove(b)

# written this way so each turtle can have it's own independent limit, as desired
while next(red, R_LIMIT) + next(green, G_LIMIT) + next(blue, B_LIMIT) < R_LIMIT + G_LIMIT + B_LIMIT:
    pass

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```